# setBackgroundResource for ImageButton of Activity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-xml

Good day! I have 1 MainActivity and several fragments. Layout of the MainActivity has 3 ImageButtons and I want to change their background from Fragment: so I have ViewPager with sliding pictures that works fine, and below the pictures I have these ImageButtons. Their background is based on what picture is right now. The pictures are changed fine but buttons backgrounds changes randomly (apparently it has some logic, but I cannot understand it). So the problem is in ImageButtons, their background aren't changed properly.

PageFragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";

    int pageNumber;

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_fragment, null);

        ImageView ivPicture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivPic);
        ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgBtn1);
        ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgBtn2);
        ImageButton btn3 = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgBtn3);

        switch (pageNumber) {
            case 0:
                ivPicture.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flowers_no_back1);
                btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_on_24dp);
                btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_off_24dp);
                btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_off_24dp);
                break;
            case 1:
                ivPicture.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flowers_no_back2);
                btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_off_24dp);
                btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_on_24dp);
                btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_off_24dp);
                break;
            case 2:
                ivPicture.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flowers_no_back3);
                btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_off_24dp);
                btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_off_24dp);
                btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_on_24dp);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

PageFragment's layout (sliding_fragment.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity with inner class MyFragmentPagerAdapter:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    NewsFragment fragmentNews;


    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;
    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private static final String TAG = "myLogs";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...
        fragmentNews = new NewsFragment();            
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_for_fragments, fragmentNews).commit();

        pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);

    }

    public void viewIsCreated() {
        ViewPager pager = fragmentNews.getPager();
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);                   

    }




    private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }

    }
}
```

fragment_news.xml (where I put ViewPager and buttons). This layout I use in class NewsFragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context=".fragments.NewsFragment">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="10">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/toggle_button_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toggle_button_size"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgBtn2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imgBtn2"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_radio_button_on_24dp"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/toggle_button_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toggle_button_size"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_radio_button_off_24dp"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/toggle_button_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toggle_button_size"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgBtn2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgBtn2"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_radio_button_off_24dp"
            android:clickable="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
...

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: declare Buttons in NewsFragment only,and access them from their.

Comment: @Ramesh Bhupathi: but how does NewsFragment find out what picture is active right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my question. So you have to put this code in MainActivity.java in viewIsCreated():

```
public void viewIsCreated() {
        ViewPager pager = fragmentNews.getPager();
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);


        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtn1);
            ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtn2);
            ImageButton btn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtn3);

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected, position = " + position);

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_on_24dp);
                btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_off_24dp);
                btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_off_24dp);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_off_24dp);
                btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_on_24dp);
                btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_off_24dp);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_off_24dp);
                btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_off_24dp);
                btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_on_24dp);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                                       int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: I hope this is not good way to implement, same line of code writing multiple time.

Comment: @Ajit: why multiply times? I didn't understand. I want to change the background of the button (the background is differenet), what's wrong?

Comment: As per the my opinion instead of changing every button background you can change only current page button and previous button background. suppose if there is 15 buttons then how will you handle(will you change 15 button background on every page)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Fragmnet to activity communication. http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/

Using interface you can achieve this

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help.I get the same result as in my code above.